# How to edit ArrayList in MainActivity from second activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-activity

I have an `ArrayList` in `MainActivity`, and I want to modify that list in `ActivityB`. How would I achieve this?

My current solution is that I made the `ArrayList` a static variable so that I can access it in `ActivityB` using `MainActivity.ArrayList`. However, I have seen that this may not be good practice and is not good information hiding. This list is the only static variable I have. Could I keep using this method or would it be better if I did something else? If so, how else could I do this?

Comment: You shouldn't have an ArrayList with data in an activity to begin with. Check clean architecture.

Comment: @m0skit0 this was how it was in my uni lab, so I followed that way. Is there anything I can do to make it more object oriented?

Comment: Too broad to explain here. Check clean architecture :) For example [here](https://medium.com/hongbeomi-dev/create-android-app-with-mvvm-pattern-simply-using-android-architecture-component-529d983eaabe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You can try to send this array from `MainActivity` to `SecondActivty` and in Your `SecondActivity` when You change that array in the way You want You can send it back and to `MainActivity`? This is sample code, I am sending `int` ( named `myValue`) from `MainActivity` to `SecondActivity` and change it there. And then send it back to `MainActivity`

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final int LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY = 1;
    public static final String MY_VALUE_KEY = "MY_VALUE_KEY";
    private int myValue = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("MyTag", "MAIN ACTIVITY. On create, myValue = " + myValue);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonGoToSecond).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                startSecondActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startSecondActivity()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(MY_VALUE_KEY, myValue);
        startActivityForResult(i, LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY)
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                myValue = data.getIntExtra(MY_VALUE_KEY, -1);
                Log.d("MyTag", "MAIN ACTIVITY. Result, myValue = " + myValue);
            }
            else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                Log.d("MyTag", "No result");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private int dataFromMain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        // Get data from MainActivity
        dataFromMain = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.MY_VALUE_KEY, -1);
        Log.d("MyTag", "SECOND ACTIVITY. Data retrieved: " + dataFromMain);


        //Do something with data
        dataFromMain *= 2;

        findViewById(R.id.buttonGoToMain).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                goToMain();
            }
        });
    }

    private void goToMain()
    {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        Log.d("MyTag", "SECOND ACTIVITY. Data send back: " + dataFromMain);
        returnIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.MY_VALUE_KEY, dataFromMain);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And the logs look like this:

```
D/MyTag: MAIN ACTIVITY. On create, myValue = 1
D/MyTag: SECOND ACTIVITY. Data retrieved: 1
D/MyTag: SECOND ACTIVITY. Data send back: 2
D/MyTag: MAIN ACTIVITY. Result, myValue = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is a great solution. I have a quick question, the onActivityResult gets called after SecondActivity finishes right?

Comment: Yes, it is called after `SecondActivity` finishes. In docs, You can read: Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the `requestCode` you started it with, the `resultCode` is returned, and any additional data from it. The `resultCode` will be `RESULT_CANCELED` if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation.